# MySQL ordering based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to query and sort records based on condition. I have tables:

- `TASKS (id, date_due, created_at, ...)` and
- `TASK_DEPENDENCIES (task_id, dependency_task_id)`, many-to-many relation table, where dependency task_id and dependency_task_id are FKs to TASKS table.

Normally I would query out tasks and order them by `date_due`. But since we have task dependencies I would like to order like this:

- first tasks that have no dependencies ordered by date_due
- next task with dependencies ordered by date_due

The solution I have now is that I simply create 2 separate queries and feed this to the table. Can this be done with only one query and how efficient (fast) it would be?

UPDATE: my existing SQL's

Non-dependcy tasks

```
SELECT T.id, TD.dependency_task_id FROM tasks T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_dependencies TD ON T.id = TD.task_id 
WHERE assigned_user_id=1 AND TD.dependency_task_id IS null
ORDER BY T.date_due
```

Depencecy tasks:

```
SELECT T.id, TD.dependency_task_id FROM tasks T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_dependencies TD ON T.id = TD.task_id 
WHERE assigned_user_id=1 AND TD.dependency_task_id IS NOT null
ORDER BY T.date_due
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I have noted that my existing solution works, I am just wondering if it can be done with 1 query!

Comment: You need to add your existing solution to your question.

Comment: Of course it could be done with 1 query, via an UNION.  Asking how fast is too open ended: are your indexes optimized for each solution, is it faster than your existing solution (which you should show for context).  Maybe you would be better off presenting your solution, building a SQLFiddle and asking the community for suggestion on improving the performance of your code.

Comment: Updated with code. @FreshPrinceOfSO I would appreciate if you removed your down-vote. I think it's a fairly legit question

Comment: @PrimozRome Done. Thanks for updating your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions in your ORDER BY clause. Let's say you have a join where you alias the TASK_DEPENDENCIES table by the name "DEP". In your ORDER BY clause, use something like this:

```
ORDER BY IF(DEP.task_id IS NULL, 0, 1), date_due
```

This will order all tasks without dependencies first (by date_due), and then tasks with dependencies afterwards (also by date_due).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to works, but I believe its `IF` instead of `IIF`?

Comment: You're right - I've been using a lot of MSSQL2012 recently. I've edited my post to reflect the MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to have two queries.  The LEFT JOIN takes care of either scenerio.  You just need another column to sort by, based on a NULL value or not

```
SELECT T.id, TD.dependency_task_id, ISNULL(TD.dependency_task_id) AS NoDependency, T.datedue
FROM tasks T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task_dependencies TD 
  ON T.id = TD.task_id 
WHERE assigned_user_id=1
ORDER BY NoDependency DESC, T.date_due
```

The performance should be nearly twice as fast, since it is only half the query

Comment: I get error with your query: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IFNULL'

Comment: sorry - should be ISNULL